# How to run a hub pulled docker image setting the environment variables

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-linux-2

I have a Django project and I'm trying to deploy it on an AWS EC2 instance.

I've created 2 docker images (application and nginx), tested locally, pushed to hub, but when I pull in my EC2 instance and try to run it, I'm getting environment variable errors like this one:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 90, in __getattr__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I've tried to create the *.env* file in the root folder and run:

```
docker run <image_id> --env-file ./.env
```

Also tried to set the varible manually with:

```
expose MY_VAR='something'
```

Still not working.

Is there a specific way to run images that was created and pushed with docker-compose, setting the environment variables?

Comment: Docker options like `--env-file` or `-e SECRET_KEY=value` need to go _before_ the image ID.  If they're after, they're interpreted as the command to run instead.

Comment: It worked! Please, post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Maze's comment solved my problem. Basically was the command syntax:

```
docker run --env-file ./.env <image_id>
```